# Building a C code with loops that counts the combinations of a number

Tags: c

I would like some help with a code I'm writing, 
I need to write a loop that counts the number of combinations for a number I input in the program, and it needs to check how many combinations I can do ,
with the numbers 10,5,2,1

for example if I input 5 there are 4 combinations - (5 | 2 2 1| 2 1 1 1 | 11111).

I have tried to make some loops but I have no idea how to make it work, I was thinking about while loop but I have no idea how to count the combinations, would really much appreciate any help in the matter.

Its not a copy of the "C - Remove Duplicate Results in Recursive Function" because I cannot use arrays, only loops...

Comment: Are there just 4 combinations? What about permutation? Eg 2 1 2 and 1 2 2.

Comment: Yes I don't need to bother with the order of the combination, just the combination itself

Comment: I feel you need some recursive function and modulo operation.

Comment: I had in mind modulo and to start with 2, and go up to 5 and then 10, but I have no idea how to write it in a loop...and even more how to count it

Comment: If you want help on your code, include the code you wrote so far.